# Lucene index not updated with Hibernate Search and Spring Data

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, spring-boot

I am getting started with Hibernate Search/Lucene using Spring Boot and Spring Data, but I am having an issue with the index not getting updated (Checked with Luke tool).

I have 3 classes in my domain. This is `Datasheet`, my root entity:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Datasheet
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private long m_id;

    @Field(name="name")

    private String m_name;

    @Field(name="description")
    private String m_description;

    @IndexedEmbedded(prefix = "documents.")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<DatasheetDocument> m_documents;
}
```

Then `DatasheetDocument`:

```
@Entity
public class DatasheetDocument
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private long m_id;

    private String m_originalFileName;

    @Field(name="componentName")
    private String m_componentName;

    @IndexedEmbedded(prefix = "manufacturer.")
    @ManyToOne
    private Manufacturer m_manufacturer;
}
```

And finally `Manufacturer`:

```
@Entity
public class Manufacturer
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private long m_id;

    @Field(name="name", analyze = Analyze.NO)
    private String m_name;

    private String m_website;
}
```

When I explicitly call `startAndWait()` on the indexer (`org.hibernate.search.MassIndexer`), then everything is as expected in the index. It contains the fields `name`, `description`, `documents.componentName` and `documents.manufacturer.name`.

However, when I now do updates through my `@RestController` classes that call into Spring Data `CrudRepository` classes, the index *only* changes when changing a *direct field* of `Datasheet` (E.g. name or description). Changing something to the `DatasheetDocument` instances does *not update* the index. Any idea why this might be?

Note that I have tried to add backreferences to the parent. For `DatasheetDocument`:

```
@ManyToOne
@ContainedIn
private Datasheet m_datasheet;
```

And for `Manufacturer`:

```
@ManyToMany
@ContainedIn
private Set<DatasheetDocument> m_datasheetDocuments;
```

But that does not help.

I am using Spring boot 1.0.1 which includes Hibernate 4.3.1. I added Hibernate Search 4.5.1. I see that Lucense 3.6.2 gets added transitively as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need the back references for sure. Without them and in particular without *@ContainedIn* there is no way for Search to know that it has to update the *Datasheet* index when the *DatasheetDocument* instance changes.

Have you added *mappedBy* to the one to many side?

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy="m_datasheet")
private Set<DatasheetDocument> m_documents;
```

Also, how to you update *DatasheetDocument*? Can you show the code? Either way, you will need to make the associations bi-directional to start with.

Answer (score -1):

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
fullTextSession.openSession()

 Object customer = fullTextSession.load( Datasheet.class, datasheetDocument.getDatasheet.getId() );
fullTextSession.index(customer);
fullTextSession.flushIndex();
```